# How to unit test to check the format of a datetime?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

My android app gives the option to select a date and a time and then it is formatted to a string with the format "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm". This string is then stored in the database.

I am trying to create a unit test that tests that the date and time are stored in the correct format but I am struggling to find the correct method to do so. I have tried this

```
@Test
public void testDateTimeFormat() {
    DateActivity dateActivity = new DateActivity();
    Calendar currentDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    Assert.assertEquals( dateActivity.showDateTime(currentDateTime), "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm");
```

The method showDateTime is fed the current date and time and it should return it in the correct format. I tried using assert equals to compare these two to show that it is in the correct format but it doesn't seem to compare it properly, it just says that they are not the same, it isn't detecting the formatting of the MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm. Not sure how I can construct this test properly

Comment: are you doing an instrumentation test? DateActivity is extending Appcompat, right?

Comment: @notTdar No I am trying to setup a unit test. I am new to testing like this so it is possible that I am doing it incorrectly. Yes, DateActivity is extending Appcompat

Comment: Alright, without instrumentation test, you can't use the instance of activity/fragment or views, you can test only Java classes who do not extend anything android related componenet.,

Comment: @notTdar thank you, I appreciate that. I'll think on finding another solution to this

Comment: good luck, "robolectric" you can explore that.

Comment: Don't use the old `Date` and `Calendar` classes; they're obsolete. Use classes from `java.time` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

Create the below method in your activity.

```
public boolean checkDateFormat(String s) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY HH:MM");
        Date date1 = new Date(s);
        s = formatter.format(date1);
        Date date = new Date();

        String strDate = formatter.format(date);
        System.out.println(strDate);
        System.out.println(s);

        if (s.equals(strDate)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and unit test code is given below

```
 @Test
    public void isDateFormat() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(new MainActivity().checkDateFormat("27/05/2019 10:06"),true);
    }
```

If you provided string is matched then test will pass and if not then it will fail.

assertEquals(new MainActivity().checkDateFormat("28/05/2019 10:06"),true);

test: Fail

assertEquals(new MainActivity().checkDateFormat("05/27/2019 10:06"),true);

test: True